# Cannot write to a folder within the exectuable's current directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, printing, directory, ofstream

I have a program that I'm attempting to write various files to.  In an attempt to clean it up I would like to put these files into a directory.  My program is running in a directory different from the sln for VS 2012 i.e. the exe is the only part of the VS files in the directory.  If I simply print the files, it's fine but if I attempt to print those same files to a different directory, then it doesn't do anything.  I printed out the directory that I'm attempting to access and I'm getting "000000" as a response.  code looks like:

```
std::ofstream output
output.open("\myFiles\entityOutput.csv", std::ios::app);
output << "print some stuff here" << std::endl;
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I haven't been able to figure out what.  Tried "\\myFiles....." already "/myFiles" etc.  I'm on a Windows 7 system as well.

Comment: What do you mean by *printing a file to a directory*?

Comment: I assume you got a warning about bad escape sequences. Since \m and \e are not defined. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because, while opening a file, you need to swap `\` with either `\\` or `/`. The reason is that `\` character is considered as a special one that's used for example to represent end of line character (`\n`).

Just swap `output.open("\myFiles\entityOutput.csv", std::ios::app);`
to `output.open("/myFiles/entityOutput.csv", std::ios::app);`, 
however make sure that the path is also correct!

Usually it's a good programming practice to check whether or not a file opening succeeded at first.

Comment: Yeah that was about right except it was "myFiles/entityOutput.csv", std::ios:app);  Thanks!!!